# how encoding & decoding works in grails with decodeHTML & encodeAsHTML in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I am trying to understand how encoding & decoding works in grails with decodeHTML & encodeAsHTML

// decode
Example is

```
List symbols = ['!', '*', '/']
symbols.each { String symbol ->
    println symbol.decodeHTML()
}
```

it should print

```
&#33;    // but it prints !
&#42;   // but it prints *
&#47;   // but it prints /
```

// encode Example is

```
List symbols = ['&#33;', '&#42;', '&#47;']
symbols.each { String symbol ->
    println symbol.encodeAsHTML()
}
```

it should print

```
'!'  // but it prints &amp;#33;
'*'  // but it prints &amp;#42;
'/'  // but it prints &amp;#47;
```

Comment: I think you have those backwards.

Comment: Sorry... din get it!!

Comment: No worries, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

`escapeAsHtml` end up calling `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` in [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

As it says in the docs for that method;

> Escapes the characters in a String using HTML entities.
>
> For example:
>
> `"bread" & "butter"`
>
> becomes: `&quot;bread&quot; &amp; &quot;butter&quot;`.
>
> Supports all known HTML 4.0 entities, including funky accents. Note
>   that the commonly used apostrophe escape character (`&apos;`) is not a
>   legal entity and so is not supported).

It does not convert all characters to their entity value, so things like `!`, `*` and `/` are left as-is.  Here's an example in Groovy:

```
@Grab( 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' )
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml

'!@£$%^&*()_+€-={}[]:"|;\'\\<>?,./~'.each {
    println "$it -> ${escapeHtml( it )}"
}
```

That prints:

```
! -> !
@ -> @
£ -> &pound;
$ -> $
% -> %
^ -> ^
& -> &amp;
* -> *
( -> (
) -> )
_ -> _
+ -> +
€ -> &euro;
- -> -
= -> =
{ -> {
} -> }
[ -> [
] -> ]
: -> :
" -> &quot;
| -> |
; -> ;
' -> '
\ -> \
< -> &lt;
> -> &gt;
? -> ?
, -> ,
. -> .
/ -> /
~ -> ~
```

Comment: "escapeAsHtml" Don't you mean `encodeAsHTML`? And if so you sure that it ends up calling `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml`? Because when I print this: `"\"café\"".encodeAsHTML()` it ends up as `&quot;café&quot;`, while if I use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("\"café\"")` it ends up as `&quot;caf&eacute;&quot;`. (It escapes the `é` as well.)